# android studio 2.0 preview instant run could not works

Tags: android

I update my android IDE to android studio 2.0 preview.but when i was going to use the new function called instant run,it went wrong and the outputs were something like "IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate class android/supportV4/app/FragmentActivity"
what is this problem and how can i fix it?(I really want to experience the new function)

Answer (score 2):

Could you share more details on how you tried to use Instant Run, on Android Studio 2.0 ?

To use instant run

1. Update android-studio to version 2.0+.
2. Open your project in studio. Go to File --> Settings --> Build  Deployment Section. Under Instant Run, Click update project.

[image: Build Execution Deployment]

This will update your android gradle plugin to the latest which is a requirement for instant run to work.Instant run also requires your project to have an API level 16 or above to work.

Note: Refer this link for more information [Instant run - android documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

Comment: i have already finished the two steps above and i can see the icon of instant run.But when i clicked the button of instant run,it went wrong and the outputs were something like "IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate class android/supportV4/app/FragmentActivity"

Comment: are you using the latest version of build tools and android support library ?

Comment: Also try the sample code for trying out the instant run.  The feature we are trying out is in its early stages of development(canary build). Dont forget that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your android studio to **Android Studio 2.1**

**Android studio 2.1 feature:-**

- Android Studio 2.1 supports Android N Developer Preview
- General Build Performance Improvements and Android Emulator
- new Jack compiler and Java 8 language support.
- performance improvements to Instant Run which leads to faster edit and deploy build speeds.